# BroadcastChannel Message Aspects

Tags: javascript, messaging

I am experimenting with Broadcast Channel API and I'm wondering if there are properties of a message. Specifically, is there a way to tell where the message originated from.

```
var bc = new BroadcastChannel("test_channel");
bc.onmessage = function (ev) {
    console.log(ev.data);
    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML += ev + '<br>';
}
```

I need to be able to separate out what color the text is in the DIV element based on where the original message came from. Whether from one website or the other.

Is there any way to tell where the message came from?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `event.origin` at `message` event handler.

Comment: Are you sure? I keep getting null.

Comment: @NoahBaxley _"I keep getting null."_ Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've never done one before. How is it different then writing the code then posting it here?

Comment: @NoahBaxley _"I've never done one before."_ , _"I am experimenting with Broadcast Channel API and I'm wondering if there are properties of a message. Specifically, is there a way to tell where the message originated from."_ ? Which description is accurate? You can verify the `javascript` at Answer at plnkr http://plnkr.co

Comment: I don't know if I could use the broadcast message API there

Comment: What do you mean? Linked plnkr is to demonstrate accessing origin at message event

Comment: In Firefox v78, `event.origin` is the URL of the sending window (as a string).  There's an `event.source` property, but for me it's *null*.